# Communicate with app via command line

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I'm currently experimenting with an java "server application", which is supposed to run in the background on a ubuntu server.
The current system isn't perfect, and that's why I want to work on a new system...
The goal is to run the java application in the background (via nohup or a linux service) and still be able to execute commands (stop status etc) to control the behaviour of this app.
I thought of creating a server socket, which is listening on localhost, which enables me to write an java "client" app which sends commands to the server and terminates afterwards...
My question is, if it is possible to avoid having such a "client" app.
It would be ideal, if i just had a way to send a string to the server using bash only (includes tools like curl for example).
Is that possible?
And is my planned system a good plan?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that JMX allows you to invoke methods in a running JVM using standard tools like jconsole and visualvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a protocol for your service.

As you said, "how about use curl"? sure , you can create a web service, with rest api.

a web service is very easy, if you just wanna to have some simple io, you can read https://www.playframework.com/ , and use it in 30 minutes (25 minutes to download the pacakges and 5 minutes to read the doc)

---

Another method is using "nc" as "client", a simple introduction page can be found here: http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/nc.1

you can write

```
echo "your command" | nc localhost 6666
```

to send a socket request to server.

However, you should define the protocol by yourself.

Comment: As I said I just need to send 2 or 3 commands... A framework like this would be overkill, since this is the only thing I'd use it for

Comment: @RoiEX oh, right. here are a few candidates: if you still would like to create a web service, you can use Jetty or Netty -- sorry they are still framework, but much smaller.

Comment: @RoiEX you can also use command "nc" and define a protocol by yourself

Comment: @RoiEX about how to use nc,  you can use 'echo "your-command" | nc localhost 6666', and the server side, you can listen localhost:6666 using socket, like here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: @RoiEX done & I do appreciate there are sth. could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

> And is my planned system a good plan?

I don't know the scope of your application, but if you are rewriting the code, consider using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)
It is so simple framework, can produce a command line app easily and can be [deployed as a linux service](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service)

so you will be able to run commands like

```
service xyz start
service xyz stop
service xyz status
```

Comment: Using Spring starts off as a simple framework, but as you embed more of your code into XML, it rarely stays that way.

Comment: AFAIK deploying my app as a Linux service works with a custom file without this framework... But still thanks for your answer

Comment: @EdwinBuck yes, and that is normal for any environment, not just spring :)

Comment: @RoiEx  You welcome... yes, it is done with an init.d script. Just wanted to propose Spring Boot in case your application will be scaled and will need something like web services in future